# Fetching from API endpoint with React returns value undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am attempting to fetch data from this NHL API: https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8477474/

When I output the call to my page it returns undefined and I can't get it to display the value. Oddly enough, the first element in the object displays correctly but not any of the nested elements.

Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from "react"

class App extends Component {
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      player: {}
    }
} 

componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({loading: true})
  fetch("https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8477474/")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
         this.setState({
           loading: false,
            player: data
         })
}) 

}

render() { 
  const fullname = this.state.loading ? "Loading..." : this.state.player.people[0].fullName; 
  return ( 
        <div>
            {fullname }
        </div> 
    )
}
}

export default App
```

This is not supposed to return undefined, because the key value is clearly there and I believe I am targeting it right.

I tried console logging but I also get undefined.
I tried as well removing the `[0]` and doing `this.state.player.people.fullName` and all kinds of alternatives but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the initial state of loading to `true`, and remove the line `this.setState({loading: true})`.

Comment: I believe this solution is more optimal because you cut down on the number of rendering. Probably okay for now, but when your app becomes bigger, you will want to cut down on unnecessary rendering.

Comment: This is the only logical solution 

Comment: @JakeMartinez it also does not make sense to set `loading` to be `false` in the initial state given that your app breaks without the data from the endpoint.

Comment: true this solution is better. i set your answer as the correct one. thanks again.

Comment: No prob. Glad to be of help

Comment: Hey also do you mind helping me to loop through like 100 players and display their names on the page? I tried a few ways but i'm looking for the most efficient method

Comment: What have you tried? And why do you think it's inefficient?

Comment: Well because i used a loop, but when you mentioned the map function i realized thats more efficient. How would you go about with the map function?

Answer (score 1):

There is a small amount of time where `loading` is false and the data isn't in `player` yet.  Try the below

```
const fullname = Object.keys(this.state.player).length ? this.state.player.people[0].fullName:""

return ( 
    <div>
        {this.state.loading ? "Loading....": fullname }
    </div> 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could initiate player state to null. Then use this line.

`const fullname = this.state.player ? this.state.player.people[0].fullName:""`

Or you could also do this with React Hooks if you wanted to as well.

https://codesandbox.io/s/baseball-fetch-api-30ehh?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [player, setPlayer] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPeople = async () => {
      await fetch("https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8477474/")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => setPlayer(res))
        .then(() => setLoading(false))
        .catch((err) => setLoading(err));
    };
    fetchPeople();
  }, []);

  console.log(player);
  const fullname = player ? player.people[0].fullName : "";
  return <div className="App">{loading ? "Loading...." : fullname}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Also do you mind helping me to loop through like 100 players and display their names on the page? I tried a few ways but i'm looking for the most efficient method.

Comment: Sure. Share a code sandbox or something. You probably just have to map through the players.  Something like players.map((player) => player.name)

Comment: here's the sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/api-fetch-using-hooks-45frh